# How do I return a space from Microsoft T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want SQL to return either `"*"` or `" "` (to get even spacing further down the line). It returns `"*"` or `""` when told to return `" "`.

From other questions and my own attempts this looks like there is no workaround. Do you have a solution?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_nettAsStar]
    (@isNett bit)
RETURNS char(1)
AS
BEGIN
    /* set space */
    DECLARE @nett char(1)
    SET @nett = ' ' 

    IF @isNett = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @nett = '*'
    END

    RETURN @nett
```

Comment: `It returns "*" or "" when told to return " "` - how do you know that?

Comment: That code should return a space. If you are using `LEN` to come to the conclusion that it is an empty string not a space then that doesn't count trailing spaces so will return zero

Comment: I ran your function and these queries return the expected '*': `SELECT [dbo].[fn_nettAsStar](1);SELECT [dbo].[fn_nettAsStar]('true');`. Show is the code you use to invoke the function. Passing 0, 'false', or NULL returns an single blank.

Comment: demo that it does return a space. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aca14cc352185e28c2ad9661b37fcb66

Comment: It looks like the OP use `LEN()` function @MartinSmith

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Martin

> If you are using LEN to come to the conclusion that it is an empty string not a space then that doesn't count trailing spaces so will return zero

when you put value `'abc'` in a field/variable of type `CHAR(5)`, the value will become `'abc  '`, but the `LEN` function will still "correctly" return 3 in that case. but if you use `DATALENGTH` instead of LEN, you will see that it is actually 5 characters long. If you define your variable with `VARCHAR(5)` then using LEN again will give you 0 length, however `DATALENGTH` will give you 1

**NOTE that: VARCHAR is Variable Length Character**

to conclude

```
@nett varchar(1) = ''  => LEN = 0, DATALENGTH = 0
@nett varchar(1) = ' '  => LEN = 0, DATALENGTH = 1
@nett    char(1) = ''  => LEN = 0, DATALENGTH = 1
@nett    char(1) = ' '  => LEN = 0, DATALENGTH = 1
```

Comment: Aside: Lest anyone assume that Unicode behaves the same way: [`DataLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) "returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression". That is rarely the number of characters in a Unicode string (`NChar`, `NVarChar` or `NText`).

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the answers. I was using the function to build a report line which comes out 1 character shorter when the "space" is returned. 
As suggested I used LEN() to check that I was getting an empty string.

My solution is to use procedural code rather than SQL to format the string.

Comment: There wasn't a suggestion to use LEN, there was a warning not to because it will give misleading results

Comment: Hi Martin, I did read and I think I understand comments regarding LEN and DATALEN. It is a confusing subject. I wonder if DATALEN returns 1 purely because of the char(1) declaration. LEN returns 0 and I seem to have an empty string so from that point of view appears consistent rather than misleading. I didn't find a solution in the comments posted but thanks to everyone.